# How can user access any of his messages after RSA encryption?

Tags: algorithm, rsa, end-to-end, encryption-asymmetric

I am planning to build a site to exchange messages securely using the **Rsa** algorithm and the **end-to-end encryption**.  Question here: As we know from RSA encryption, if User1 wants to send a message to User2.  User 1 requests User2's public key and encrypts the message.
User 2 can learn the message’s content by decrypting it using his private key.
Well ... how will the first user be able to access his message after it is encrypted?
It was stored in the database in an encrypted form.
There is an option to solve the problem but I think it is impractical.
When User1 creates a message to send to User2, he encrypts it with his public key and keeps it in the database
Then he encrypts the original message with User 2's public key and also saves it in the database.
Do you have any alternative solutions or suggestions?
thnx

Comment: The solution for your problem is the usage of a key exchange protocol like Diffie-Hellman: both parties exchange their public keys and in the second step they build a "sharedSecret" with the own private key and the exchanged (from third party) public key. The sharedSecret can be used for AES encryption and as the AES key is known (and identical) on both sides both parties can decrypt the messages that are stored as encrypted message in the database.

Comment: *...but I think it is impractical...* It is not impractical, that's the common and right way to do it provided you replace *..encrypts the message with the public key...* with the hybrid encryption scheme suggested in @MichaelFehr comment and the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The messages between User 1 and User 2 can be encrypted using a symmetric cipher with a key which they both share and only use for messages to each other. The key itself can be stored encrypted with User 1's public key, and separately stored encrypted with User 2's public key, so that each user is able to access the symmetric key to decrypt messages they sent as well as messages they received.

Comment: Well ... what I'm going to do now is use the AES algorithm and I'll encrupt the message using the AES key and then encrypt that key with RSA. Now if USER 1 wants to send a message to USER 2, it encrypts the AES key using its public key. It also encrypts it using the public key of USER 2, and two keys are stored, one encrypted with the USER 1 public key and the other with the USER 2 public key is that correct ?.